# Disable textbox when other textbox is empty

Tags: vb.net

i was trying to disabling the Basic Rate textbox when Present days is empty 
and enabling it when it has some numbers. im having a problem when i put numbers in present days it will not enabling the textbox in basic rate.

```
Private Sub UserControlAdminPayroll_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If txtPresentDays.Text = "" Then
        txtBasicRate.Enabled = False
    Else
        txtBasicRate.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check every time that the `txtPresentDays.Text` changes. Try this:

```
Private Sub txtPresentDays_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPresentDays.TextChanged
    txtBasicRate.Enabled = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPresentDays.Text)
End Sub
```

Don't forget to set `txtBasicRate.Enabled` to an appropriate value at start-up.